# How to transform jquery grep function with functional programming paradigm?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm the very beginner in functional programming and I want to transform the grep function in jquery.
I just want to detect *my incorrect point in the code* not just answer.

The original grep function is

```js
function grep( elems, callback, invert ) {
        var callbackInverse,
            matches = [],
            i = 0,
            length = elems.length,
            callbackExpect = !invert;

        // Go through the array, only saving the items
        // that pass the validator function
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            callbackInverse = !callback( elems[ i ], i );
            if ( callbackInverse !== callbackExpect ) {
                matches.push( elems[ i ] );
            }
        }

        return matches;
    }  


grep([1,2,3,4,5], function(k){return k<4}, true);
```

And my code is

```js
function my_grep(elems, callback, invert) {
  var callbackInverse,
    matches = [],
    i = 0,
    length = elems.length,
    callbackExpect = !invert;

  let fun = 
    matches => {
    let r = R.range(0,length);
    let modify = R.curry(
        p=>{
            let callbackInverse = !callback( elems[ p ], p );
            if ( callbackInverse !== callbackExpect ) {
                matches.push( elems[ p ] );
            }
        }
    );
    R.map(modify,r);
    return matches;
   };

  fun(length); 
}
console.log(
  my_grep([1,2,3,4,5], function(k){return k<4}, true)
)
```

Please just point out what I did incorrectly in my code.

For example, in original grep function,

```
grep([1,2,3,4,5], function(k){return k<4}, true)
```

makes output

```
[4,5]
```

But my code make error saying

```
matches.push( elems[ p ] );

TypeError: matches.push is not a function
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56199503/edit) and then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] with input and expected output

Comment: I made you a snippet. Now show and tell us what does not work

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know what is snippet. So what is the problem in my code? What should i do for identical operation with the original grep function?

Comment: Dunno. Show the call with input and tell us expected behaviour/output

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote the call with input and expected output

Comment: Add the code to the snippet!!!

Comment: `matches =>` redefines the array from earlier

Comment: I added to snippet but i does not work as i've expected.  What it means "matches => redefines the array from earlier" ?

Comment: You have matches=[] which defines an array. Then you redefine matches to a function with the matches => which of course does not have a push  method

Comment: Perhaps change the matches=> to something else. I’m on my mobile so cannot rest

Comment: `R` is not defined is now the first error

Comment: Thank you but i was defined earlier and i didn't write it. I resolve by adding return fun(length);

Comment: Please make the snippet give only the errors you are having trouble with. Why is it hard to understand people are not going to help you unless you help them help you